# How do I find what I flagged?

Tags: support, feature-request, flagging

I was looking at how helpful my flags have been [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/151595), but I couldn't work out what I had flagged. Is there a link to the specific comment or answer within a question?

It's important for me to know which comment I flagged when the flag is declined, in order to learn how to flag better.

I'm adding the `feature-request` tag after Daniel's comment, because those sorts of links can be created.

Secondly, I can't find my declined edits (does this deserve a separate question?).

Comment: For comment flags, you can't know which comment you flagged, unless you remember which it was. For post flags, there is a link to the post you flagged, the question title in the flag history entry.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know how to reach the post, but for questions with a lot of activity, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668645/151595), finding a comment I flagged six months ago is near impossible.

Comment: Yes, for comment flags, you practically let go of the ball the moment you flag. You can still see it for a bit (you don't immediately forget which comment you flagged), but when it's out of sight, it's gone. Re rejected edits: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/151595/ahorn?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). While you still have only few suggestions, it's easy to find the rejected ones, when you have many, not so easy, but you'd mainly be interested in recent rejections probably, so would look only at the first few pages.

Comment: We ordinary users cannot view your Flag Summary page, but I know from looking at my own that it identifies the post (by Question or Answer) and whether the flag was "helpful, disputed, or declined".  Comment flags are handled a bit differently, since Comments are more ephemeral by design than Questions and Answers, so I'd recommend lowered expectations for being able to look through any detailed information about those.  Counts of the helpful Comment flags are all that I see in my history.

Comment: Here is a related post about declined flags on Comments: [What kind of comments are not constructive?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12741/what-kind-of-comments-are-not-constructive)  @WillieWong gives some moderator perspective from 2014 in a highly upvoted Answer.

Comment: Re: *I can't find my declined edits* You should be able to find your suggested edits in your profile, try [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). However, this includes both approved and rejected edits. (BTW this information in your profile is visible to other users, too.)